# Assigning weight to different factors to arrive at probability

Tags: probability

Developing a report to determine probability of an outcome for a user.

Looking to find the percentage chance that this probably will happen.

Have about 10 factors that each have their own weight of how they affect that outcome.

Here would be an example of some of those, with a weight estimation of 1 to 5, with 1 meaning it affects least, and 5 meaning it affects most.

Age (4)
Education (3)
Times Used Service (2)
Gender (1)
Past Experience (1)

Based on a specific users data for each of the above, I want to use the importance (weight) factor for each item to determine the percentage chance of an outcome.

Note: I am a mid-level programmer - but far from a mathematician!

Comment: do you know in advance the weight ? if so you have some kind of formula already. if not, you might want to read about logistics regression.

Comment: @d_e thanks for the feedback. I will look into that!